# Different uname -a output

Tags: linux

I am looking for different output of the `uname -a` command.

The one that I have is
`Linux dogeserv.net 5.4.0-89-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 14:50:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I am looking for different outputs of Processor (other then x86_64 and aarch64), OS , -m output.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so please tell us the programming context.

Comment: For unix commands help, try `command --help` (so here `uname --help`) or check the man page (here `man uname`) or try a web search.

Comment: `HP-UX arw0120 B.10.20 A 9000/861 2012830765 two-user license` `Linux arw0191.mra.roland-man.biz 2.4.31 #1 Tue Jul 12 10:10:53 MEST 2005 i686 unknown` `Linux raeksrv1vm 2.6.32-64bit #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 08:34:51 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux` `Linux raeksrv2 2.6.32-44-pve #1 SMP Wed Jan 13 11:07:55 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux` `Linux axc3051 4.4.19-rt27 #1 PREEMPT RT Tue Oct 1 13:10:22 CEST 2019 i686 GNU/Linux` `Linux arw1027 4.9.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.272-1 (2021-06-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux` `Linux localhost.localdomain 4.14.139-rt66 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Tue Oct 1 08:11:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: To make it clear: I think you are asking if people can provide different outputs of `uname -a`? You are not seeking for help with the `uname` command, right? Perhaps you can clarify for what purpose you are asking this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As per the time i am writing the answer, these options are available in `uname` command.

```
-a, --all                print all information, in the following order, except omit -p and -i if unknown:
-s, --kernel-name        print the kernel name
-n, --nodename           print the network node hostname
-r, --kernel-release     print the kernel release
-v, --kernel-version     print the kernel version
-m, --machine            print the machine hardware name
-p, --processor          print the processor type (non-portable)
-i, --hardware-platform  print the hardware platform (non-portable)
-o, --operating-system   print the operating system
```

For some reason, it's not showing my processor, but you can use `uname -p` for processor information.

---

Incase you want detailed information about your processor, you can use `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, and this will show you information about the processor of your computer with information of every single core and this is what your output should look like

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 142
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0xea
cpu MHz         : 1279.215
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
.....
```

TO be more specific you can use these commands for their respective outputs

```sh
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'vendor' | uniq        #view vendor name
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq    #display model name
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l      #count the number of processing units
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'              #show individual cores
```

A alternative to `cat /proc/cpuinfo` is `lscpu`, it will also give you information about your processor, but it will be more about the whole processor instead of every single core.

this is what output should look like:

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  BIOS Vendor ID:        Intel(R) Corporation
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20GHz
    BIOS Model name:     Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               142
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  2
.....
```

---

Lastly [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is for mostly programming related questions, you can see all the sites [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) offers for different type of questions to be asked by clicking this [Link](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)